# A plane, a game, a piece of fame

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> I might be undressed or impressed,
>   Altered to be more, cut to be less.
>
> A plane, a game, a piece of fame,
>   A noteworthy aspect of one's claim.
>
> Though no life, still life teems,
>   A medium of creators dreams.

Who/what am I?

Comment: When you say who am I? Is there a clue in there that it's a person?

Comment: @MasterYoda No it could be a what, sorry if that led to any confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Card

I might be undressed or impressed,

> Can be blank or printed, or embossed

Altered to be more, cut to be less.

> Can be used in ways that give it more purpose, surface area, visibility, etc. and cut into smaller sizes

A plane, a game, a piece of fame,

> Can be plain or folded into a plane, used for a game (playing cards etc.), or you might hand someone 'your card' as an introduction or to get your name around

A noteworthy aspect of one's claim.

> Cards may be used as evidence of identity when claiming e.g. club membership

Though no life, still life teems,

> card is non-living but could be covered in microbial life?

A medium of creators dreams.

> A drawing/art medium

OR Similarly

> Paper(s)

I might be undressed or impressed,

> Can be blank or printed, or embossed

Altered to be more, cut to be less.

> Can be used in ways that give it more purpose, surface area, visibility, etc. and cut into smaller sizes

A plane, a game, a piece of fame,

> Can be plain or folded into a plane, used for a game (Sudoku etc.), or you might end up in a newspaper or similar

A noteworthy aspect of one's claim.

> 'Your papers' may be used as evidence of identity or ownership

Though no life, still life teems,

> paper is non-living but could be covered in microbial life? OR from @RobertColumbia answer 'Canvas is not alive in a biological sense, but one can paint a "still life" portrait on it.'

A medium of creators dreams.

> A drawing/art medium

Comment: Your second guess is correct, look to @RobertColumbia for the "Though no life, still life teems" line.  Spot on for the rest of the interpretations though :)

Comment: All three mediums have so much in common it'd be hard to create a puzzle referring to any of them that didn't seem broad but maybe the wording could be changed to more explicitly refer to the correct answer rather than another similar multifunction medium?  Tricky without making the puzzle easier though...

Comment: The lines themselves could point to many things, but combined I feel that it gives a direct enough answer. "a noteworthy" and "a plane", not any others that fit that as closely as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are

> Canvas

I might be undressed or impressed,

> Canvas can be bare, or it can be printed upon. It can also be pressed like cloth.

Altered to be more, cut to be less.

> One can use canvas to make something, and one can cut parts out of it to get a smaller piece.

A plane, a game, a piece of fame,

> 1) Some aircraft [have canvas wings](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43021/how-are-wood-and-canvas-wings-able-to-sustain-damp-and-bad-weather). 2) The HTML `<canvas>` element [is used in making browser games](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_canvas.asp). 3) Canvas is turned into famous artwork by painting upon it.

A noteworthy aspect of one's claim.

> Canvas is used to make tents, and pitching a tent is a way to stake a claim on some land. One can also make canvas rope, and use it with some wooden pegs to create a border line ("staking out" a claim).

Though no life, still life teems,

> Canvas is not alive in a biological sense, but one can paint a ["still life"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Still_life) portrait on it.

A medium of creators dreams.

> Artists paint beautiful pictures on canvas!

Comment: Super great guess!!! You are right on some of the interpretations but that's not the answer I was looking for. Doesn't quite fit the part of "noteworthy aspect" or "a plane". Mull it over a bit more, you're almost there :]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> Paper .... It can be undressed / impressed, can be altered to be more  and cut to less, can play games with it, make plane with it. Can be piece of fame or claim in the form of a certificate/ ID cards. Even though its lifeless, painting on a paper can make the art alive.

Comment: How does your answer add to the identical one already given? You should always look at existing answers before providing one of your own, to ensure you are not just adding a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

It could be

> The Oscar award (the physical statue)

As,

> The statue is a bare one
>
> The movies which need to win Oscar should be more creative but less censored
>
> A game/plane ( to be provided)
>
> It is a piece of fame
>
> It is also worth for claiming by cine producers/directors
>
> the statue has no life but many carve about it
>
> It's an inspiration for directors to innovate.

Comment: You forgot to address this line "Altered to be more, cut to be less", but I think that some of those interpretations were a bit of a stretch though.